# Why does this simple E-Mail validation not execute?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this simple form validation script for the school, but the function which checks the e-mail, called `absender()`, doesn't work, and I don't get why. The other two functions, which are validating the names do work. I literally trying for days and hours now, any help is much appreciated.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  'use:strict';

  var nachName = document.getElementById('Nachname');
  nachName.addEventListener('blur', nName);

  var vorName = document.getElementById('Vorname');
  vorName.addEventListener('blur', vName);

  var absender = document.getElementById('Absender');
  absender.addEventListener('blur', absender);

  function nName() {
    var re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

    if (re.test(document.Formular.Nachname.value)) {
      document.getElementById("formuText").innerHTML = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("formuText").innerHTML = "Fehlerhafte Eingabe!";
    }
  }

  function vName() {
    var re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

    if (re.test(document.Formular.Vorname.value)) {
      document.getElementById("formuText").innerHTML = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("formuText").innerHTML = "Fehlerhafte Eingabe!";
    }
  }

  function absender() {
    var at = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;

    if (at.test(document.Formular.Absender.value)) {
      document.getElementById("formuText").innerHTML = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("formuText").innerHTML = "Fehlerhafte Eingabe!";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="Formular">
  <p id="formuText"></p>
  <fieldset name="fieldset">
    <legend>Persönliche Daten</legend>
    <p id="formText"></p>
    <label for="Nachname">Nachname</label>
    <input type="text" id="Nachname" placeholder="Mustermann" name="Nachname">
    <label for="Vorname">Vorname</label>
    <input type="text" id="Vorname" placeholder="Max" name="Vorname">
    <label for="absender">E-Mail:</label>
    <input type="text" id="Absender" name="Absender" placeholder="MaxMuster@Mann.de">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work"? What is the expected output and what is the output that you get?

Comment: @Nikem it is not executing. Read the answers. I changed the title again to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element variable and validation function have the same name.

```
...
var absender = document.getElementById('Absender'); // <-- this variable
absender.addEventListener('blur', absender);
...
function absender() {                             // <-- has the same name of this function
  var at = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
...
```

**They can't have the same name.** Roughly, they "occupy the same namespace".

**To fix**, rename either the function or the element:

```
var absenderElement = document.getElementById('Absender'); // notice the variable rename
absenderElement.addEventListener('blur', absender);
```

In the example above, the variable was renamed from `absender` to `absenderElement`, so the function can keep the name `absender()`.

Answer (score 0):

- You call the var the same as the function and wipe it.

  `var abs = document.getElementById('Absender');`
  `abs.addEventListener('blur', absender);`
  fixed that
- Also your label for needs to point at the Absender
- Also no need to access the field by id inside the event handler

```js
window.onload = function() {
  'use:strict';

  var nachName = document.getElementById('Nachname');
  nachName.addEventListener('blur', nName);

  var vorName = document.getElementById('Vorname');
  vorName.addEventListener('blur', vName);

  var abs = document.getElementById('Absender');
  abs.addEventListener('blur', absender);

  function nName() {
    var re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if (re.test(this.value)) {
      document.getElementById("formuText").innerHTML = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("formuText").innerHTML = "Fehlerhafte Eingabe!";
    }
  }

  function vName() {
    var re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

    if (re.test(this.value)) {
      document.getElementById("formuText").innerHTML = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("formuText").innerHTML = "Fehlerhafte Eingabe!";
    }
  }

  function absender() {
    var at = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;

    if (at.test(this.value)) {
      document.getElementById("formuText").innerHTML = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("formuText").innerHTML = "Fehlerhafte Eingabe!";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="Formular">
  <p id="formuText"></p>
  <fieldset name="fieldset">
    <legend>Persönliche Daten</legend>
    <p id="formText"></p>
    <label for="Nachname">Nachname</label>
    <input type="text" id="Nachname" placeholder="Mustermann" name="Nachname">
    <label for="Vorname">Vorname</label>
    <input type="text" id="Vorname" placeholder="Max" name="Vorname">
    <label for="Absender">E-Mail:</label>
    <input type="text" id="Absender" name="Absender" placeholder="MaxMuster@Mann.de">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```